# Remote UI Script on win7 in logged off state

Tags: winapi, windows-7, psexec, win32gui, win32-process

I am using psexec to run a remote script which does some UI operations on the print objects present in the remote system. To be specific , the API used is SHInvokePrinterCommand() to invoke printer properties of a printer object.

The entire thing works fine when executed with a user logged in(and thus a visible desktop) on windows 7. But when no user is logged in , the procedure is failing to work, the API(SHInvokePrinterCommand) returns successfully but it doesn't seem to do any work. WINDOWS XP under the similar conditions, WORKS FINE.

The observation made me believe that it has something to do with the session and "Window station" architecture that varies within these operating systems.
With some coding in the remote process , I was able to establish that the remote process is started in a non-zero session (session 2) by psexec and the only window station it is attached to is "WinSta0".(I used EnumWindowStations() for that). WinSta0 is the only windows station which receives input from KeyBoard , mouse etc.

With this much observation , I fail to understand what makes the entire thing not work in case of windows 7, with no on logged in. Basically the properties page of printer is not actually getting invoked in this case.
Does the session , that psexec forms , for executing the remote process ,in some way not a "complete" session? Any way to fix this problem?

Any ideas or suggestion are most welcome.

Comment: Can you share the psexec command line?  There are a number of options there for specifying user name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Several things come to mind, mostly related to increased security in Windows Vista & above.

1. `SHInvokePrinterCommand` is deprecated in Vista & above.
2. PSExec runs the script in a service, which in Vista & above [no longer have desktop access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463428.aspx).
3. When there's no logged in user, HKEY_CURRENT_USER *doesn't exist*, and any attempts to read from it will fail.

Comment: Eric , thanks for your response. As I mentioned , The entire thing WORKS when there is a user logged on to the system. But fails where in there is no one logged in. PS exec does run a service in the remote machine, which in turn runs the target executable in the  user account specified by the user in the command line while invoking psExec. The target executable itself does not run as a service, as per my understanding. I am using the -i ,-u , -p options to specify the admin user name and password of the remote machine. -h and  to elevate the privilege and -c to copy the exe to the remote sys.

Comment: @user1624807 I looked at the source, and while it's a maze o twisty little passages, I did see some registry references to HKEY_CURRENT_USER, which doesn't exist when there's no logged-in user.  And, by my reading of [how PsExec works](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/psexec), PsExec doesn't create a complete session; it uses the current session.

Comment: Thanks again for your response. Which source you are talking of?

Comment: Windows source code ? whoa! I actually managed to solve the problem with a specific switch in the psexec itself. Thanks for all your help. Wonder how you were able to get the source code of windows though :P